# jQuery tagit plugin, public methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, public-method, tag-it

Does anyone know if the tagit jQuery plugin has a public method for removing just 1 specified tag from the list?

I saw there is for removing (clear) all tags from the list, but I would need to remove only 1 tag :P

Also, how to call all the public methods from outside of tagit() call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. Just wrap a public function around _popTag in the widget code, e.g.

```
removeTag : function(label,value) {
    this._popTag(label, value);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
$(myElement).tagit("removeTag", label, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [jQuery UI Tag-it plugin by aehlke](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown), then these instructions will provide the plugin with this functionality:

Syntax:

```
// removes the tag called "outdated-tag"
$("#mytags").tagit("removeTagByName","outdated-tag");
```

Add this method right below the removeAll method in the tag-it.js file:

```
removeTagByName: function(tagName) {
        var that = this;
        this.removeTag(this.tagList.children('.tagit-choice').find("input[value='"+
                tagName +"']").parent(), null);
}
```

**NOTE:** You *are* modifying a code library! So be sure to document what you're doing with clear code comments and otherwise documenting this change so that when you or a colleague update the plugin to another version, you're sure to include this functionality and not be baffled by why things suddenly stopped working ;)